# DateTime.ParseExact throws System.FormatException in japanese

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have the follow code that throws System.FormatException. The exception message is localized to Japanese so I suspect that could be due to some local settings on the machine. Any suggestions what can cause that issue?

Here is simplified code:

```
 string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss";

            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"...\New Text Document.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.SetLength(0);

                var test = new Test();
                test.AccessDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
                
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
                using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(w, openFiles);
                }
            }

            DateTime d;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"...\New Text Document.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
                Test test = (Test)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);

                d = DateTime.ParseExact(test.AccessDateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }


       [DataContract(Name = "Test")]
        public class Test
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "AccessDateTime")]
            public string AccessDateTime { get; set; }
        }
```

I tried to pass Japanese culture to date.ToString(..) method but everything works as expected and ParseExact works fine.

Comment: `DateTime.ToString(String)` uses the current culture, which is probably Japanese, but you are using the invariant culture when converting back to `DateTime`. What are you trying to do here? Can you use the invariant culture when formatting the date too?

Comment: Your code says the string goes through a DataContractSerializer. You can make sure you get the expected format back from the DataContractSerializer?

Comment: @Sweeper - the current culture shouldn't matter because of the fixed format, or? - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5W7Dqw

Comment: as shown in my dotnetfiddle (prev comment) your code doesn't cause your claimed error

Comment: Is is possible invariant culture to be used when formatting the date too. The idea here is to store the datetime into an external file so the app can read that date later. The strange thing here is that I passed Japanese culture(with various data/time separators) to datatime.ToString method but the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Your format does not contain anything culture specific like the dateseparator / so i assume the given Culture given to the parsing methods (atleast the shown ones) do not matter. You might still want to ask the user of the machine where it fails if he changed the windows regional settings. As long as no one plays around with the threads CurrentCulture it will use a culture derived from the regional settings so might be derived from the japanese settings here but different.

Comment: Updated to full source code of the actual serializing/deserializing process. I cannot ask the user because it is unknown.

Comment: "Is is possible invariant culture to be used when formatting the date too." - Yes. Use `value.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: @Ralf: The default calendar system is part of the culture information as well - and even how numbers are represented. The culture *always* matters, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet Calendar is a Good Point. I looked at the source if i see something culture specific but lost track at some point.